# Ksh ls -1 not working as expected

Tags: ksh, ls

For the command `ls`, the option `-1` is supposed to do run `ls` yielding an output with only one column (yielding one file per line). But if I put it in a script, it just shows every file jammed on one line, separated with spaces.

Script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

text=`ls -1`
echo $text
```

Folder contents:

```
test
  |--bob
  |--coolDir
  |--file
  |--notThisDirectoryAgain
  |--script.sh
  |--spaces are cool
  |--thatFile
```

Script Output:

```
bob coolDir file notThisDirectoryAgain script.sh spaces are cool thatFile
```

Output if I run `ls -1` in the terminal (not in a script)

```
bob
coolDir
file
notThisDirectoryAgain
script.sh
spaces are cool
thatFile
```

Comment: try `echo "$text"`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*it just shows every file jammed on one line, separated with spaces.*

You have to consider what **it** is.

When you do

```
text=`ls -1`
```

that runs the program `ls` and presents the output as if you typed it in.  So the shell gets presented with:

```
ls=file1
file2
file3
etc.
```

The shell splits command-line tokens on whitespace, which by default includes a space, a tab, and a newline.  So each filename is seen as a separate token by the shell.

These tokens are then passed into `echo` as separate parameters.  The `echo` command is unaware that the newlines were ever there.

As I'm sure you know, all `echo` does is to write each parameter to stdout, with a space between each one.

This is why the suggestion given by @user5228826 works.  Change `IFS` if you don't want a newline to separate tokens.

However, all you really had to do is to enclose the variable in quotes, so that it didn't get split:

```
echo "$text"
```

By the way, using `backticks` is deprecated and poor practice because it can be difficult to read, particularly when nested.  If you run `ksh -n` on your script it will report this to you (assuming you are not using an ancient version).  Use:

```
text=$(ls -1)
```

Having said all that, this is a terrible way to get a list of files.  UNIX shells do globbing, this is an unnecessary use of the `ls` external program.  Try:

```
text=(*)             # Get all the files in current directory into an array
oldIFS="$IFS"        # Save the current value of IFS
IFS=$'\n'            # Set IFS to a newline
echo "${text[*]}"    # Join the elements of the array by newlines, and display
IFS="$oldIFS"        # Reset IFS to previous value
```

Comment: Instead of using the extra `oldIFS` variable, you can also run this is in a subshell: `(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${text[*]}")`

Comment: Great answer.  Perhaps add a line to say that `ls` doesn't even need `-1` in non-interactive use?

Answer (score -1):

That's because you're capturing ls output into a variable. Bash does the same.

Comment: So variables aren't allowed to have newlines, they just convert them to spaces? Seems kind of dumb to do that. It's completely unintuitive.

Comment: Try this one:

    #!/bin/ksh
    IFS='' text=`ls -1`
    echo $text

Comment: It's not dumb and it is not unintuitive.  It only seems that to you because you don't know how the shell works.  UNIX shells were never intended as end-user tools.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. Shell variables *can* contain newlines. However, they get eliminated on extrapolation unless the variable is quoted.